# ggplot: Add legend and remove padding of graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, legend

I currently use [following script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right/3117319) to plot a graph with one common x and two distinct y-axes:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
scaleFactor <- max(mtcars$cyl) / max(mtcars$hp)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp)) +
  labs(title = "My Plot") +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=cyl), method="loess", col="blue") +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=hp * scaleFactor), method="loess", col="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="cyl", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="hp"))
```

[image]

Questions:

1. How can I add a legend on the top left within the graph?
2. How can I remove the spacing to the left and right of the x-axis? Note: `+ scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))` works perfectly in the example above, but in any other given time series, it returns *"Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied"`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that these are two very different questions, it would have been better to split them.

You need to put both `color` inside the `aes()`, use then `theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.2))` to move the legend.

Note that the colors now won't correspond (they are just "labels"), you should to define your own color scale and legend with `scale_color_manual()`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp)) +
  labs(title = "My Plot") +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=cyl, col="blue"), method="loess") +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=hp * scaleFactor, col="red"), method="loess") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="cyl", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="hp")) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied"

Is probably because `x` in that case is `as.Date` type, `scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0))` works.

Here an example:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(
  dates = seq(from=as.Date("2018-01-01"), to=as.Date("2018-01-10"), by="day"),
  val1 = sample(10),
  val2 = sample(10)
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=dates)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=val1, color = "red")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=val2, color = "blue")) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.2)) +
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="val2", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./1, name="val2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I will improve my questions :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to RLave's answer, the labels assigned in the legend you'll notice don't correspond to colour. To change this, assign the `col=` commands in `aes` to the label text, and add `scale_fill_manual` to choose the colours:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp)) +
  labs(title = "My Plot") +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=cyl, col="cyl"), method="loess") +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=hp * scaleFactor, col="hp"), method="loess") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))+
  scale_y_continuous(name="cyl", sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="hp"))
```